# How to show latest article for parent category in WordPress menu on hover

Tags: php, css, wordpress, menu

[click here to see sample image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUgq7.jpg)

Am trying to show latest article on my wordpress menu on hover but i don't have any idea on how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`wp_get_recent_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts)**. You can call the following inside your **WordPress** menu and customize it to your liking:

```
<?php
  /* Only Get 1 Post In Defined Category */
  $args = array(
    'numberposts' => '1',
    'category' => 'your-category'
  );

  /* Get Recent Posts */
  $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
      echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '"><img src="../your-image"></a>';
    }
  wp_reset_query();
?>
```

You'll need to set the `img` `src` with whatever method you are using with **WordPress**, like the [featured image](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails).

Comment: Wherever you want it to appear in your theme.

Comment: well, i want it to show beside the drop down on menu hover just as you can see in the picture above. i want to know the exact place where i can add the code

Comment: Most likely `header.php` if I had to guess. You'll want to hire someone if you're not able to implement the code above. This is a very basic `php` loop that can be placed wherever you want. If you don't know what file to put it in, I don't think anyone is going to help. This is a site for that allows you to ask for help, not a site where people write all of your code for you.